# Add external NLB as target group of ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-nlb

is it possible to add external facing NLB as target group of ALB?
I am getting error

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the RegisterTargets operation: 
The IP address '54.xxx.xxx.xx' is not allowed,
as it must be an address from a VPC subnet, RFC1918, or RFC6598
```

while calling `aws elbv2 register-targets` API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to add NLB IP addresses as target group of ALB as long as NLB is internal and both are in same VPC or their VPCs are peered

Answer (score 1):

From your error I see uou are trying to add public ip as Target which not supported 100%.

You can only have rfc1918 range for this.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. NLBs can target ALBs. ALBs cannot target NLBs.